# Directing script output to a file using subprocess?

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

From within a python script ("main.py"), I am using the subprocess module to run another script ("sub_script.py").

Here's the code in the "main.py" script that 'runs' "sub_script.py":

```
subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "sub_script.py"])
```

this works fine as long as "sub_script.py" does not have any "print" statements in it.

I now want to channel all the output of "sub_script.py" to an external file ("log.txt").

How do I do it?

Comment: Why not just `import sub_script`?  Why all this extra subprocess business?

Comment: I am running "main.py" using Cron -- so it is helpful for me to use subprocess.

Comment: `import` and launching a subprocess do fundamentally different things. For starters, the script won't run with import at all if it uses `if __name__ = "__main__":` block, you'd have trouble forwarding the output (which is required here), and your main script would need to wait for the subscript to finish. Also you can't really import a script in the general case (because you don't have any guarantee that it is a .py file in the python path).

Comment: @user540009: "so it is helpful for me to use subprocess"?  Why?  Please explain why. @Rosh Oxymoron: Using `import sub_script` is not the entire line of code required, more would be needed, clearly.  "Forwarding the output" from the original script and the original script which imports and executes `sub_script.py` does not change.  I'm not sure what "import a script in the general case" means since importing a script requires some design work, i.e., setting `PYTHONPATH`.  The question remains.  Why not simply import and execute `sub_script`?  Why try to use subprocess?

Comment: simple. I want the process to run in the background.

Comment: @user540009: Why isn't the main script (`main.py`) running in the "background"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "sub_script.py"], stdout=open("log.txt", "a"))
```